# CSS navigation menu

Tags: css, html, forms

I found a few discussions for CSS navigation menus. But they are different from my problem.
I have `CSS navigation menu`, what supposed to be is, the tab is  changed to white once it is clicked, normal is red and hover is black. Now it doesn't work that way.

Only `class="current" (tabs-1) is white always` and the rest are always red, even I clicked ,they don't change to white.

[image]

The code is shown below.

```
mainpage.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<style type="text/css">
#background {background: url(main_background.jpg);}


/*Top menu css*/
hr {
    border:none;
    border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:1px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    }

#maintopmenucontainer{
    height:24px;
    background:#000;
    display:block;
    padding:45px 0 0 15px;
    }

#maintopmenu{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvitica,sans-serif;
    }

#maintopmenu ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:auto;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 20px 0 20px;
    height:19px;
    background:transparent url(maintopmenu_bg-OFF.gif) no-repeat top left;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:transparent url(maintopmenu_bg-OVER.gif) no-repeat top right;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li a.current,#maintopmenu ul li a.current:hover{
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    }
/*Top menu css*/

</style>


</head>

<body>

<hr />
<div id="maintopmenucontainer">
  <div id="maintopmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="current"><span>Landed</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Apartment</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Condominium</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span>Commecial</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-5"><span>Farm</span></a></li>

    </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1">
         <?php include 'mainpage_menu_landed.php'; ?>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-2">
         <?php include 'mainpage_menu_landed.php'; ?>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-3">

     </div>
     <div id="tabs-4">

     </div>
     <div id="tabs-5">

     </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#maintopmenu" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
</html>
```

mainpage_menu_landed.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<style type="text/css">
#background {background: url(main_background.jpg);}


/*Drop Down Menu */
fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;

    }
    select {
      width: 150px;

    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
/*Drop Down Menu*/

.button {

border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff3019+0,cf0404+61 */
background: #ff3019; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff3019 0%, #cf0404 61%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 61%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ff3019 0%,#cf0404 61%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3019', endColorstr='#cf0404',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 12px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75) 0 1px 0;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Segoe;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 100px;
text-align: center; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="background">
<form name="Landed"  id="Landed" method="post" >
<br /><br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="divstate" id="divstate" >
      <optgroup label="Divisions" selected="selected">
      <option>Yangon</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="States">
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
      <option>13</option>
      <option>14</option>
      <option>15</option>
      <option>16</option>
      <option>17</option>
      <option>18</option>
      <option>19</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="township" id="township" >      
      <option>Yangon</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input maxlength="100" type="text" name="min_price" id="min_price" placeholder="Minimum price"/>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input maxlength="100" type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price" placeholder="Maximum price"/>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="button" onclick="searchButtonAction()" id="search" href="#">Search</a>
<br /><br /><br />
</form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problems are definitely coming from your content loading inside your tabs. If you leave out your <?php> content from your tabs they work normally. I will try and recreate your situation on my server. Please re-post your mainpage_menu_landed.php so I can add it to my environment for testing. Thank you.

Comment: @c00ki3s Yeah but when you click, it doesn't change to white. Tab-1 is always white. Because Tab-1 is class="current".

Comment: Check out my edited answer. Styling should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

So I did some research and you need to do some jQuery handling on those active tabs. I've edited the css, html and added the jQuery script to your document. Now, styling works fine on my end. Test it.

**Source:** http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery

Here is the edited document for your mainpage.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            hr {
                border:none;
                border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
                height:1px;
                margin-bottom:25px;
            }

            #maintopmenucontainer{
                height:24px;
                background:#000;
                display:block;
                padding:45px 0 0 15px;
            }

            #maintopmenu{
                position:relative;
                display:block;
                height:24px;
                font-size:11px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvitica,sans-serif;
            }

            #maintopmenu ul{
                margin:0px;
                padding:0;
                list-style-type:none;
                width:auto;
                }

            #maintopmenu ul li{
                display:block;
                float:left;
                margin:0 1px 0 0;
            }

            #maintopmenu ul li a{
                display:block;
                float:left;
                color:#fff;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding:5px 20px 0 20px;
                height:19px;
                background:#ff3019;
            }
            #maintopmenu .tab-links a:hover {
                background:#ffffff;
                color:#000;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
            #maintopmenu .tab-links li.active a, 
            #maintopmenu .tab-links li.active a:hover {
                background:#ffffff;
                color:#000;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

<hr />
<div id="maintopmenucontainer">
  <div id="maintopmenu">
    <ul class="tab-links">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-1"><span>Landed</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2"><span>Apartment</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3"><span>Condominium</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-4"><span>Commecial</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-5"><span>Farm</span></a></li>

    </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1" class="tab active">
         <?php include 'mainpage_menu_landed.php'; ?>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-2" class="tab">
         <?php include 'mainpage_menu_landed.php'; ?>
     </div>
     <div id="tabs-3" class="tab">

     </div>
     <div id="tabs-4" class="tab">

     </div>
     <div id="tabs-5" class="tab">

     </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
    //MANUAL TAB STYLING
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#maintopmenu .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#maintopmenu" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

**NOTICE:** Don't forget to add your background images. I've removed those lines from css for testing purposes.

Comment: Exactly, it is working for all issues. Loading form as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();` with `$( "#maintopmenu" ).tabs();` at the footer.

Comment: Yeah I found that mistake, but still the same.

Comment: is there showing any consol error? can you give me a jsfiddle demo?